# BottomSheet is intercepting touch events from RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

I'm using a RecyclerView inside the bottom sheet from google support library. I have noticed that sometimes bottom sheet intercepts touch events. I have not found any answers to this issue.

My screen looks like this

[image]

Code for the layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/appColor">

    <ui.view.GMapView
        android:id="@+id/gMapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mBottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="160dp"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/uiColor"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvAddresses"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />


    </FrameLayout>  

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For that you need to stop scrolling of recycler view, below is the solution for that,

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```